# Rxjs: Observable with takeUntil(timer) keeps emitting after the timer has ticked

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have run into a very strange behavior of `takeUntil()`. I create an observable timer:

```
let finish = Observable.timer(3000);
```

Then I wait for some time and call

```
// 2500 ms later
someObservable.takeUntil(finish);
```

I would expect said observable to stop emitting after the timer "ticks", i.e. about 500ms after its creation. In reality **it keeps emitting for 3000ms after its creation**, way beyond the moment when the timer "ticks". This does not happen if I create the timer with a Date object containing absolute time value.

Is this by design? If yes, what is the explanation?

Here's complete code, runnable with node.js (it requires `npm install rx`):

```
let {Observable, Subject} = require("rx")
let start = new Date().getTime();
function timeMs() { return new Date().getTime() - start };

function log(name, value) { 
    console.log(timeMs(), name, value);
}

Observable.prototype.log = function(name) {
    this.subscribe( v=>log(name,v), 
                    err=>log(name, "ERROR "+err.message), 
                    ()=>log(name, "DONE"));
    return this;
}

let finish = Observable.timer(3000).log("FINISH");
setTimeout( ()=>Observable.timer(0,500).takeUntil(finish).log("seq"), 2500);
```

This generates the following output:

```
2539 'seq' 0
3001 'FINISH' 0
3005 'FINISH' 'DONE'
3007 'seq' 1
3506 'seq' 2
4006 'seq' 3
4505 'seq' 4
5005 'seq' 5
5506 'seq' 6
5507 'seq' 'DONE'
```

If I create the timer using absolute time:

```
let finish = Observable.timer(new Date(Date.now()+3000)).log("FINISH");
```

Then it behaves as expected:

```
2533 'seq' 0
3000 'seq' 'DONE'
3005 'FINISH' 0
3005 'FINISH' 'DONE'
```

This behavior seems to be rather consistent in various situations.E.g. if you take an interval and create child sequences using `mergeMap()` or `switchMap()`, the result would be similar: child sequences keep emitting beyond the finish event.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are forgetting the first rule of cold `Observables`: Each subscription is a new stream.

Your `log` operator has a bug; it is subscribing once to the `Observable` (thus creating the first subscription) and then returning the original `Observable`, which get subscribed to *again*, implicitly, when you pass it to the `takeUntil` operator. Thus in reality you actually have two `seq` streams active, both of which are behaving correctly.

It works in the absolute case, because you are basically setting each stream to emit at a specific time, not a *relative* time to when the subscription occurs.

If you want to see it work I would suggest you change your implementation to:

```
let start = new Date().getTime();
function timeMs() { return new Date().getTime() - start };

function log(name, value) { 
    console.log(timeMs(), name, value);
}

Observable.prototype.log = function(name) {
    // Use do instead of subscribe since this continues the chain
    // without directly subscribing.
    return this.do(
      v=>log(name,v), 
      err=>log(name, "ERROR "+err.message), 
      ()=>log(name, "DONE")
    );
}

let finish = Observable.timer(3000).log("FINISH");

setTimeout(()=> 
  Observable.timer(0,500)
    .takeUntil(finish)
    .log("seq")
    .subscribe(), 
2500);
```

Comment: You are giving me too much credit: I never knew the rule of cold observables in the first place :) Are you saying that timer() starts counting time only after it is subscribed to, and the counting is started anew for each new subscription? Frankly, there is nothing in the documentation of the timer() method that would imply that, except perhaps the mention of "async IScheduler", which was probably copied from .NET implementation and makes little sense to me in JavaScript context.

Comment: No worries, it is a common enough mistake. It isn't something specific to the `timer` operator, it is a more general behavior inherent to the Observables. They are intended to be lazily evaluated. See this fairly good primer on [hot vs. cold](https://medium.com/@benlesh/hot-vs-cold-observables-f8094ed53339)

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, here's the code that actually does what I wanted. By using `Observable.publish().connect()` it creates a "hot" timer that starts ticking immediately, and keeps the same time for all subscribers. It also avoid unwanted subscriptions in the "log" method, as suggested by @paulpdaniels.

Warning: beware of the race condition. If the child sequence starts after the timer has ticked, it will never stop. To demonstrate, change timeout in the last line from 2500 to 3500.

```
let {Observable, Subject, Scheduler, Observer} = require("rx")
let start = new Date().getTime();
function timeMs() { return new Date().getTime() - start };

function log(name, value) { 
    console.log(timeMs(), name, value);
}

var logObserver =  function(name) {
    return Observer.create( 
      v=>log(name,v), 
      err=>log(name, "ERROR "+err.message), 
      ()=>log(name, "DONE"));
}

Observable.prototype.log = function(name) { return this.do(logObserver(name)); }

Observable.prototype.start = function() { 
    var hot = this.publish(); hot.connect(); 
    return hot; 
}

let finish = Observable.timer(3000).log("FINISH").start();

setTimeout(()=> 
  Observable.timer(0,500)
    .takeUntil(finish)
    .log("seq")
    .subscribe(), 
2500);
```

The output is

```
2549 'seq' 0
3002 'FINISH' 0
3006 'seq' 'DONE'
3011 'FINISH' 'DONE'
```